# Как Telegram Desktop нормально работает из коробки без прокси?

Tags: proxy, telegram

Скачал портативную версию Telegram (для Windows) с официального сайта. Естественно без VPN туда не пробиться.
Запустил exe-шник, ввел номер телефона, ввел код из смс и через пру секунд в приложение подгрузились все мои чаты.

На ПК VPN не установлен, только расширение в Chrome и то оно было выключено. Посмотрел в настройки Telegram Desktop и увидел такое:
[image: Telegram Destop advanced settings]

Как я понимаю, в приложение уже зашиты некоторые адреса прокси серверов и они автоматически используются.

Собственно вопрос:
Как/почему эти встроенные прокси еще живы? РКН ведь частенько банит прокси, которые используются для доступа в Telegram (по крайней мере в Андроид приложении у меня минимум 1 раз в треть года бесплатный прокси, специализировавшийся на Telegram, становится недоступным).

P.S.
И еще вопрос немного не по теме:
Если на территории России Telegram заблокирован (по крайней мере так пытаются сделать), то как/почему мне приходят смс с кодом от Telegram? Разве операторы не могут их блокировать или просто всем абсолютно пофиг?

Comment: System proxy settings это прокси-настройки вашей системы, а не вшитые в телеграм адреса.

Comment: @Эникейщик, как это? С Windows 10 поставляется список proxy серверов? У меня на ПК нет никакого приложения связанного с proxy и VPN, только расширение в Google Chrome.

Comment: Не нужно додумывать. Никто не говорил о списке прокси, поставляемом с вин10. System proxy settings это настройки прокси, которые вы настроили в системе. Причём "Нет прокси" это тоже настройки прокси.

Comment: @Эникейщик, я никакие прокси в системе не настраивал. Если, как вы сказали, "Нет прокси" это тоже настройка, то как тогда Telegram отправляет и принимает данные?

Comment: Видимо, предположение, что "без VPN туда не пробиться" неверно.  Кстати, прокси и впн не одно и то же.